# How to clone a debian 4.9 virtual sever?

Tags: mariadb, debian, virtual-machine

I have to change some settings on a production (virtual) server where debian 4.9 is running and includes a big database. So i searched via google for a good solutions because i'm not so fit with unix-commands and there is no space for to do mistakes or shut down the system for a few days.

Settings:

- Linux v22017033447646597 4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u1 (2017-12-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux
- PHP 7.2.27-1+0~20200123.34+debian9~1.gbp63c0bc (cli) (built: Jan 23 2020 14:14:52) ( NTS )
- Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
  with Zend OPcache v7.2.27-1+0~20200123.34+debian9~1.gbp63c0bc
- Server version: 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.1

I'll glade for any sensefull response..

Comment: Debian 4.9? Which VPS-vendor?

Comment: Hm, you mean the name of the hoster? It is a german company. Sorry, i'm not shure, that i understand your Question.
I'm thinking abbout a solution where i use a real Machine here in my Company and implement there a docker container with debian and than clone evrything from the productionserver into this container.
Do you think, this is a good solution?

Comment: I misinterpreted "virtual". Sorry I cannot help you. What is the benefits of Docker for you?

Comment: For me it is easyer to build a docker container on my local machine as to rent for money a virtual server by an hoster. When i want to clone than, i hope also that the processing time is not so long.

Comment: what setting changes? How much downtime is allowed? For risk mitigation, create a test server that is identical and practice. Docker has many uses, however glossing over weaknesses in unix skills isn't a use case.

Comment: Thx for answer, i know the best practice is to create a test server, but this cost money, knowledge (cloning) and time. I jumped in this project to help the people, because they can't make a shutdown and there is a Zend-Application (ver. 2.4) with PHP 5.6 what is unsecure. So i thougth, i create on my local machine a docker container with debian 4.9 and than copy everything with scp to that container, make a mysql-dump (1 million entries) and create a database in my docker container and find a way to update than the application to PHP 7.4.